# Running an SDL program

Tags: c, runtime, sdl-2

So I've recently started to learn SDL2, and I am trying run a simple program, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My IDE (Code Blocks) says that the line of code SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO); has some kind of error and won't run. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

static const int width = 800;
static const int height = 600;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO); // <-Supposed Error

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hey\n", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_SetRendererDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(running)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the error is ... ?

Comment: @Stargateur I don't know, if you read my code I added a comment that that shows which line of code contains an error. To be specific I'd assume I made a syntax error in that line of code. If you can't the line of code, the code says  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

Answer (score 0):

The linker error that I get is:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_SetRendererDrawColor'
```

Because this function doesn't exist in SDL2, you must use `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()`.

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, but the error that I'm dealing with is the line of code that says  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

Comment: @VictorGonzalez Considerate to accept this answer if this solve your problem, [tour]. Code block must have tell you the error, you should take time to learn how to use Code block.